# MoveIt! - Markers missing on custom Robot, IK-Planning not working

Tags: ros, moveit, ik, interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there,

I've been trying to get my MoveIt-project to work similar to the pr2 demo, but I'm unable to get the markers to appear.
I have seen and read, that other users had issues with this, too, and tried the suggested solutions. But none of them fixed the issue in my case.
So I have tried multiple different approaches through the MoveIt setup assistant, defined the robot-arm as a chain instead of joints, set a parent group for the gripper... but no luck.

Im using the Robot [lwa4p](https://github.com/mas-group/schunk_modular_robotics/tree/indigo_dev/schunk_description/meshes) from Schunk with a very simple gripper, consisting of 3 boxes.
**Also**: The planning of paths doesn't work at all with my robot.

Any Ideas for the cause of my problems?

(if i had >points, i would upload my xacro and a screenshot :D)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260870/moveit!---markers-missing-on-custom-robot,-ik-planning-not-working/) by [David_111](https://answers.ros.org/users/30233/david_111/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2017-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One of the reasons for markers not appearing and IK not working is the IK solver not being specified. You have to specify the IK solver in the config file. This can be done manually or through the setup assistant.

Does your kinematics.yaml file have the following?

```
  name_of_kinematic_chain:
    kinematics_solver: kdl_kinematics_plugin/KDLKinematicsPlugin
    kinematics_solver_search_resolution: 0.05
    kinematics_solver_timeout: 1
    kinematics_solver_attempts: 10
```

If not you could add it. Replace the "name_of_kinematic_chain" with yours.
Hope it helps!

---

Originally posted by [hc](https://answers.ros.org/users/27378/hc/) with karma: 114 on 2017-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David_111](https://answers.ros.org/users/30233/david_111/) on 2017-05-03**:
That did solve the marker Problem! And obviously it solved the planning path not working problem :D
Thanks!